# Get Port of running play microservice within a guice module

Tags: scala, playframework, microservices, service-discovery

I'd like to start a play application at a random port (port 0). Each started microservice instance should connect to a service locator (eureka) and tell him his port and host. But how can I retrieve the port of a running play service?

This question was actually asked several times, but the answers did not work for me:

```
class MyModule @Inject() (configuration: Configuration) extends AbstractModule {
  configuration.getInt("http.port") // returns None
  System.getProperty("http.port") // returns null
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/SettingsAkkaHttp) this should work:

```
configuration.get[Int]("play.server.http.port")
```